# How can I make items grow before wrapping?

Tags: css, flexbox

If I have 5 flex items that cannot fit on less than 3 lines, how can I make sure the item that is 'larger' than the others is the one with the `.big` style? Whether that be the item is on a line by itself, or the item grows before other elements with lower `.flex-grow` values?

So given the below, the result is:

```
 [   big   ][small]
 [ small ][ small ]
 [      small     ]
```

When what I want is:

```
 [      big       ]
 [ small ][ small ]
 [ small ][ small ]
```

Alternately with a bigger container, we can get:

```
[  big  ][small][small]
[  small  ][  small   ]
```

whereas I'd want:

```
[    big   ][ small ]
[small][small][small]
```

Is this doable?

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.big {
  background-color: blue;
  min-width: 400px;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.small {
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big">Big</div>
  <div class="small">Small</div>
  <div class="small">Small</div>
  <div class="small">Small</div>
  <div class="small">Small</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle for first case](https://jsfiddle.net/o4phb6d7/3/)

[jsfiddle for second case](https://jsfiddle.net/o4phb6d7/2/)

Comment: Set the width for `.big` to 100%?

Comment: Maybe it's not 100% though - it could be `[   big   ][ small ]` on the first line and `[small][small][small]` on the 2nd.

Comment: `how can I make sure the item to get it's own line is the one with the .big style?` Means `.big` should always be on it's own line,  What @j08691 said answers your question

Comment: I'll edit; the question was more properly articulated in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the "@media(max-width:800px)" seemed to be the best solution.

Checking for container width when page loads is also achievable with jQuery. Then changing containers width accordingly is another solution that involves a little more work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    
    .container {
      width:800px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .big {
      background-color: blue;
      min-width: 400px;
      flex-grow: 2;
    }

    .small {
      background-color: green;
      min-width: 300px;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
    
    /*Set media max width*/
    @media(max-width: 800px){
        .container {
          width:800px; /*Make width shroter if media-width < 800px*/
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="big">Big</div>
      <div class="small">Small</div>
      <div class="small">Small</div>
      <div class="small">Small</div>
      <div class="small">Small</div>
    </div>
       
</body>

<!-- If you want to go the jQuery/JS route.. here's a start -->

<!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Get width of container
    var containerWidth = parseInt($('.container').css('width'));

    //If container width is less than 800(px), then loop through all containers with the class of "big" and change their min-width
    if(containerWidth > 800){   
        for(let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.big').length; i++){
            document.querySelectorAll('.big')[i].style.minWidth = '800px';
        }
    }
    
</script> -->
</html>
```

Comment: 2 questions..  1.Are you doing this because of the screen size? or the actual size of the container ... 2. If you are cool with a answer in jQuery, if so I can do this no prob. but if you need it in pure CSS maybe look into "@media(max-width=800px){ your css here }" will work if your changing the elements due to screen resizing.

Comment: Little of each; the idea is that the .big styled element makes better use of extra space than .small elements, whether that's due to container size change or different screen sizes. I could set width:<const>px on smaller media sizes, but then I create this sorta transparent relationship between the media styles and the container elements. I suspect it's what I'll have to do, I was just hoping css could handle that for me if I supplied the info about 'what should grow first'.

Comment: I see, ya the best route to go would be to set the max width of the media. I will change my answer accordingly. Like I said this could be done in jQuery with a little extra work, let me know if that would be possible for you and I could add it into the answer as well. Hope this helped.